# Imprimir exponente en python

Tags: python

Hola buenas presento la siguiente duda.
como puedo hacer para que en la pantalla se imprima una letra con su exponente

ejemplo un `x` elevado al cuadrado

```
from random import choice
import string
class NumRnd():
    lista = [item for item in range(1,10)]
    c1 = str(choice(lista))
    c2 = str(choice(lista))
    c3 = str(choice(lista))

class VarRnd():
    var1=choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    var2=choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    var3=choice(string.ascii_lowercase)

print(VarRnd.var1)
```

Quiero que al imprimir `VarRnd.var1` le imprima un exponente

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SO en español. Edita la pregunta, e indica en texto el código que has intentado realizar. 
Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Comment: Listo ya la he editado apropiadamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se trata de una terminal de texto, como supongo, éstas no tienen la capacidad general de poner como exponente cualquier caracter. Para ello deberías tener un entorno que te permita mostrar salida en formato HTML, como un Jupyter Notebook.

En una terminal estás limitado a los caracteres que tenga la fuente en tu terminal. Si tu terminal soporta unicode, puedes hacer uso de algunos símbolos que Unicode define para exponentes numéricos ([vease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_blockU%60))

Por ejemplo, para imprimir un "elevado al cuadrado", el símbolo Unicode es U+00B2, que se ve así: `²`. Para usarlo en Python tienes dos opciones:

```
print("{}²".format(VarRnd.var1))
print("{}\u00B2".format(VarRnd.var1))
```

En el primero he metido el `"²"` directamente como parte de la cadena, para lo cual he tenido que copiarlo y pegarlo desde una página Web, pues mi teclado no tiene forma (que yo conozca) de introducir directamente ese símbolo. El segundo método es más fácil de teclear, siempre que sepas el código del carácter Unicode.

En realidad hay una tercera forma, y es usando `chr(codigo)` y en este caso puedes poner el código en hexadecimal como `0x00B2`, o en decimal, que sería 178.

### Caso general

Para exponentes entre 1 y 9 la cosa se complica un poco, ya que los exponentes 2 y 3 tienen códigos pequeños (178 y 179 respectivamente, o 0xB2, 0xB3 en hexadecimal), pero los exponentes 0, 4, 5, ... 9 tienen códigos grandes (0x2070, 0x2074, 0x2075, ..., 0x2079). Y el exponente 1 "va por libre" y tiene código 0xB9.

Podemos hacer una función que reciba el exponente deseado como parámetro y devuelva el carácter Unicode correspondiente como resultado:

```
def unicode_exp(exp):
    if exp == 1:
       return chr(0xB9)
    if exp == 2 or exp == 3:
       return chr(0xB0 + exp)
    else:
       return chr(0x2070 + exp)
```

Y podrías usarlo así:

```
base = 5
exp = 4
print("{} elevado a {} se ve así: {}{}".format(base, exp, base, unicode_exp(4)))
```

En mi terminal funciona y se ve así:

[image: terminal]

Pero quizás en la tuya al final no se vea, si la fuente instalada no tiene los correspondientes caracteres Unicode.

Para un caso más general aún, con exponentes mayores de 9, tendrías que escribir una función que vaya obteniendo los dígitos del exponente y convirtiendo cada uno al correspondiente carácter Unicode.

Comment: Muchas gracias fue muy util tu respuesta